# Can't see map after renaming fields using Table Manager plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I'm quite the beginner at using QGIS and I'm not sure what I did.

I tried renaming two of my columns/fields using the plugin Table Manager, and after changing the names, my map no longer appears.  I feel that it should be an easy fix but can't figure out what to do at all.

Comment: Can you post a part of the Attribute table?

Answer (score 1):

Have you used a styling depending on the fields you just have renamed?

You can add the datasource a second time (the field names should have changed there already), copy the style if necessary and delete the first layer entry.

Comment: Thank you!  Didn't realize I could just add the datasource again.  Very simple solution to a problem that looked daunting.